# JuiceSSH android rsa key

Tags: ssh

I am using JuiceSSH on android to connect to an ssh server running on my linux box.

I would like to authenticate using an RSA key pair.

Am I able to do this using JuiceSSh on android?

Does anyone know where the settings are to import an RSA key. I can't seem to find them anywhere.

Comment: I disagree since this se is for super users and says nothing about your OS right. It belongs here.

Comment: "android" is the OS in question, "JuiceSSH" is an android-only ssh client app.  see instructions in the [SU android tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/android).

Comment: Super User is for "computer enthusiasts and Power Users", not for any specific OS. SSH is for power users. It belongs here.

Comment: true, and true, and irrelevant.  your question is about configuring a particular SSH client, not a general SSH question.  don't worry, if the moderators decide the question belongs elsewhere it can be moved.

Comment: @quixotic _unless they specifically involve interaction with a computer_ I think could apply here.

Comment: The purpose of this restriction isn't to keep people from asking question we don't want to see on SU, it is to make sure the question gets asked in the place best able to provide the best answer. It is also to avoid tension between the various communities from the idea that one may be accepting questions that would drive traffic and users to the sites that question may better belong in. Importing of the key occurs on the SSH client, and therefore the primary topic of your question is within the Android ecosystem, not the host you're connecting to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create New Identity you have Private key option, you can paste or generate new keys.